# Issue with recognizing methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm a new coder and I'm having some trouble with my methods. I made a few but they aren't being detected in the main method. (P.S I havent filled most of the methods yet because I want to remedy the problem first.)
Thanks everyone.

```
package area;
     import java.util.*;

     /**
      *
      * @author domendes
      */

     public class Area {


         public static void main(String[] args) {
             Scanner kbdln = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Welcome to the area calculating code! Which shape would you like to calculate the area of?");
             System.out.println("Press 1 for a Triangle, 2 for a Circle, 3 for a Rectangle, and 0 to quit.");
             int request = kbdln.nextInt();
             if (request == 1) {
                 areaTriangle();
             } else {
                 if (request == 2) {
                     areaCircle();
                 } else {
                     if (request == 3) {
                         areaRectangle();
                     } else {
                         if (request < 1) {
                             System.out.println("Goodbye");
                             return;
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

         }

     }

     public static void areaTriangle() {
         Scanner kbdln = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Welcome to the Tirangle area cacluator. Enter in the height of your triangle");
         double triBase = kbdln.nextDouble();
     }


     public static void areaCircle() {

     }

     public static void areaRectangle() {}

     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not detected in the main class?" What are the exact errors you're getting, and where in the code are they located? (Mark the line with a comment or something.) You're missing a closing bracket (`}`) in your code sample, and it's not clear whether that's an error in your original code, or in creating the question.

Comment: Are you getting any error message or it just doesn't do anything? If there isn't, you throw a `System.out.println("area such and such method");` in those empty methods to see if they are being executed.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, everything is an object. So the methods that you are creating are actually methods which belongs to your `Area` class. If you want to access them you have to use `Area` class to refer to them.

Given that you have created `static` method (which means that your methods are at class level and not at object level. you should read more about it). You can access them using `classname.methodname`. In your case it would be `Area.areaTriangle()`.

Comment: You don't need to use the class name if the `static` methods are in the same class, as they are in the OP's code sample: https://ideone.com/op0jer (The code sample could be bad, but this doesn't seem to answer the question as-written.)

Comment: I know but i didn't want to mix up this concept with the basic concept. Op seems to be struggling with the basic concept so i wanted to put in `ELI5`

Comment: Well, the OP came here with a problem they're not communicating very well, since the code in their question doesn't compile. What I'm trying to point out is that until the question is less bad, there's no way of knowing this is the right answer. Basically, you're solving a problem you wish the OP had, but don't know whether or not they do.

Answer (score 0):

Your if/else statements are poorly structured. The first statement should be `if`, each statement following it should be `elseif` and the very last one should be `else`. However in this case a switch statement would be best

```
switch(request){
    case 1:
        areaTriangle();
        break;
   case 2:
        areaCircle();
        break;
   case 3:
        areaRectangle();
        break;
   default:
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 woops thanks for that. Used copy/paste to save time and forgot to go back and change values.

Answer (score 0):

> they aren't being detected in the main method

The main method is a static context, which means if you are trying to call those methods from outside the Area class, you would have to do `Area.areaTriangle()`, for example.

Alternatively, you could define an `AreaPrompter` class, that would be like so.

Then, if you want to use those methods in any other class, you can do

```
AreaPrompter prompter = new AreaPrompter();
prompter.whateverMethodNameHere();
```

---

```
public class AreaPrompter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AreaPrompter prompter = new AreaPrompter();
        // main method
        prompter.run();

        // just the triangle method
        prompter.areaTriangle();
    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner kbdln = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the area calculating code! Which shape would you like to calculate the area of?");
        System.out.println("Press 1 for a Triangle, 2 for a Circle, 3 for a Rectangle, and 0 to quit.");
        int request = kbdln.nextInt();

        if (request <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            return;
        } else if (request == 1) {
            areaTriangle();
        } else if (request == 2) {
            areaCircle();
        } else if (request == 3) {
            areaRectangle();
        }
    }

    public void areaTriangle() {
        Scanner kbdln = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Tirangle area cacluator. Enter in the height of your triangle");
        double triBase = kbdln.nextDouble();
    }


    public void areaCircle() { }

    public void areaRectangle() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press 1 for a Triangle, 2 for a Circle, 3 for a Rectangle, and 0 to quit."
int num = sc.nextInt();
    if(num == 1){
     areaTriangle();
    }else if(num == 2){
     areaCirlce();
    }else if(num == 3){
     areaRectangle();
    else{
       System.out.println("GoodBye");
    }
```

There is nothing wrong with the way you calling your methods since the main method is `static` you can call the `static` methods directly without the use of any objects of class etc.